# ggplot: boxplot sort

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I sort a boxplot in ggplot?

Here's what I'm trying to plot:

```
qplot(  row.names(pcaDF),pcaDF[,1],data=pcaDF,geom="boxplot") + coord_flip()
```

and here's the structure of `pcaDF`

```
> str(pcaDF)
'data.frame':   108 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ sort(plotdata[, 1], decreasing = F): num  -5.89 -5.52 -4.66 -4.54 -3.92 ...
```

Comment: It's hard to answer without a reproducible example, but in brief, create a data frame and then use reorder to change the order of the rownames.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting in ggplot is regulated by the levels in the factors.  To control the sorting of factor: A in df:

```
df$A = factor(df$A , level = sort(unique(df$A)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered here:
[ggplot: how to specify vertical order of multiple boxplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464552/ggplot-how-to-specify-vertical-order-of-multiple-boxplots)

Others finding this question and wanting to reorder (sort) other data with ggplot may find the following post useful.
[How to order breaks with ggplot / geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000670/how-to-order-breaks-with-ggplot-geom-bar)

If other searchers still are lost trying using the keyword "order" in place of "sort" as this seems more fruitful from experience. :-)