# How to make boxplots with data formatted as indicators 1 and 0?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and want to make boxplots based on my data, in which each category will be plotted based on Price. My data is in the form:

[image: data]

For example I would like to have a boxplot of price vs storage where Storage would be categorized as 64GB, 256GB, other_GB, NA_GB. How to group those into one category "storage" would be useful as well. After an initial boxplot I could tell price and the other variables were scaled differently so I want to know how to make R recognize "1" for a variable like 64 GB means to count one 64 GB that sold at the corresponding price. Thanks for any help

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data instead of images as we can't copy it for testing thecode

Comment: Use the reshape2 library function melt() on your dataframe to convert it from wide to long with id.vars = "Price" to preserve the Price column. This should condense all those columns into many rows and 3 columns, and your life will be so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any sample data, so I'm simulating some data similar to yours to demonstrate.

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    Price = sample(85:200, 20) * 100,
    x64_GB = sample(c(0, 1), 20, replace = T),
    x256_GB = sample(c(0, 1), 20, replace = T),
    other_GB = sample(c(0 ,1), 20, replace = T));

library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(key, value, 2:4) %>%
    filter(value > 0) %>%
    ggplot(aes(key, Price)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Explanation: Change your data from wide to long format, remove `0`s, and use `ggplot` to show `Price` distribution per `key` as boxplot.

If you want to change the order of the boxplots, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867393/how-to-change-order-of-boxplots-when-using-ggplot2).